# blender color management and compositing problem

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management

i have a question about color management in fusion:

what should I do if I have a blender render in exr, and I want to blend that with stock footage and pngs in srgb color space?

i know I should convert the stock footage to linear first then blend with the blender render. BUT after the compositing i have to convert the blender render to filmic srgb by adding the ociocolorspace node at the end, then problems appear, the stock footage seems washed out.  if I convert everything to regular srgb then the blender render is overexposed and oversaturated,

so what I usually do is convert the stock footages to srgb and blender render to fimic srgb separately then combine them in the end. that way I get the correct color. but the limitation is I can't do any complex blending between them. because they are all in the srgb space now and all the srgb problems will appears if I try to do anything to them.

so what should I do here?

thanks

Comment: Umm, I totally got lost in there. However, do you know about the color management render settings?

Comment: the setting is fimic,

in short, whats the proper workflow for combining blender render with srgb pngs and videos in compositor like fusion?

Comment: Ok. Just checking.

Comment: Well, afaik blender assumes all imported images and videos are sRGB, so…